# Is there a term for an uplayable Solitaire hand?

Tags: terminology

Occasionally I deal myself a hand in solitaire - Klondike - that is unplayable. It's so infrequent that I feel as if I've dealt myself a winning hand - in Bizzaro world possibly. I was thinking there's some poetical quality to this hand I'm unable to use. Is there a term for that I might use? Are there any playing card scholars out there?

Answer (score 1):

At casinos I have played at it is called a "trash hand".  The casinos allow redeal if unplayable.  This happens 1/400-500 times.  I have never had this happened but have seen it happen and the redeal.  Not sure "trash hand" is local or a given for Klondike.

Comment: I think you *could* apply it but, as I mention in my answer, I think it is essentially a poker/casino term.

Comment: Trash hand or garbage hand is an unplayable hand in casino lingo.  You hear it in almost every game.  I have seen signs at casinos that say "Redeal on all trash hands."  Not that I look for my local casinos for the meanings of words.  But if you said "I was dealt a trash hand", I think most people would understand you.

Comment: Yes, that was my suspicion -- there's nothing wrong with the term per se other than that it's essentially *casino* lingo rather than solitaire lingo.

Answer (score 1):

In the games literature I've read (I'm not a "patience scholar", but I am the author of a couple of pieces of patience software, so I have read a few books on the subject), I'm not sure there's a single term for precisely what you're asking for. However, the following may help:

- A game is described as being **blocked** if no moves are possible, and
  that state can be referred to as a **block**.
- The word **stalemate** can also be applied to patience.
- An **impasse** is either a combination of cards/part of a layout that
  blocks the game.

You could adopt RyeBread's casino term, but I don't think it's generally used 'in the patience literature' as it were.

Answer (score 0):

you could say you are ***stumped*** or ***stymied*** or ***snookered***

The last two can be used in their noun forms for the hand - as in *that's a snooker/stymie*

> ***stumped***
>
> at a loss, at one's wits' end, at sea, baffled, brought to a standstill, floored
>
> ***stymie***
>
> a situation or problem presenting such difficulties as to discourage or defeat any attempt to deal with or resolve it.
>
> in *golf*: to impede with a stymie
>
> ***snooker***
>
> To leave one's opponent in the game of snooker unable to take a direct shot without striking a ball out of the required order.

Comment: Neil has some context.  Not a downvote but have never heard those in the terms of card games.

Comment: I've heard stumped quite often. I thought snooker is quite apt. Nothing wrong with transferring concepts.

Comment: Stumped maybe, but refers to no more moves not no moves from the start.

Comment: in that case you say 'stumped at the start' - when you have a hand during the game and reach an impasse you say I'm stumped. 'Snookered' is a common enough usage too. And I think 'stymie' works as a noun to describe the hand rather than your situation.

Comment: as for stymie the concept is transferrable from the game of golf.

Comment: I think you could use the above in informal speech, but they don't occur in the 'solitaire literature', as it were.